# c++ win32 DLL - need to dynamically load a base64 string (very strange!)

Tags: c++, winapi, dll, base64, ram

First of all, sorry if the title isn't really accurate, I have no idea how I can put my problem into a single sentence.

The problem I'm facing is that I have a win32 DLL which needs to dynamically load a binary file and do something with it (the binary file is found in a base64 string, which the DLL then decodes and writes to disk).

Pretty simple, in theory. However, here come the problems:

1. I tried putting the string into the resources by an external program. That worked and it does appear in the resources (according to reshack), BUT when I try to access it from inside the DLL it doesn't work. And yes, I do know that you need the hInstance of the DLL itself, not from the executable file that contains it, it didn't work either though.
2. I also tried to load the string from another source (I tried file, URL and even the registry), but whenever I save it in a variable, the program crashes ("X stopped working" message), I'm assuming that the program which loaded the DLL didn't clear enough RAM to store that extra variable.

And last but not least an extra note: I do not have access to the source code of the program containing the DLL (I'm writing a plugin more or less), so I couldn't pass a parameter either.

I really hope someone can help me out of this dilemma.

Edit: Code upon request

Method 1: Loading the base64 string from a resource

```
HMODULE handle = itsamee; // "itsamee" was set in DllMain
HSRC hResa = FindResource(handle, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_PEFILE), "BASICFILE"); // IDR_PEFILE is 300
if(hResa == 0)
    printf("FAIL"); // it ALWAYS prints "FAIL" ...
```

.rc file:

```
#include "resource.h" // there it just defines IDR_PEFILE and includes <windows.h>
LANGUAGE LANG_ENGLISH, SUBLANG_ENGLISH_AUS
IDR_PEFILE BASICFILE "app.txt"
```

Method 2: Loading the base64 string from the registry

```
HKEY hkey;
RegOpenKeyEx(root, key, 0, REG_READ, &hkey); // "root" is "HKEY_CURRENT_USER" and "key" is "software\\microsoft\\windows\\currentversion\\run"
DWORD type = REG_EXPAND_SZ;
DWORD cbData;
RegQueryValueEx(hkey, name, NULL, &type, NULL, &cbData);
char* value = new char[cbData];
RegQueryValueEx(hkey, name, NULL, &type, (LPBYTE)&value, &cbData); // "name" is "pefile"
RegCloseKey(hkey);
// now here I had two lines of code. the first one is:
printf("Okay"); // it would always print "Okay"
// this is the second version:
printf("Okay, value is %s", value); // it wouldn't print this, instead I'd get the "X stopped working" error
std::vector<char> dec = base64_decode(value); // this would never happen, "stopped working", regardless of which printf was called before
```

Comment: Code, or it never happened. Or, more formally, when a developer describes his implementation, he never mentions that piece of code where he introduced a bug. To help yourself get better help, please post the code that doesn't produce the expected result.

Comment: For the registry version, try allocating an extra byte for `value`  and filling it with zero.

Comment: You should also show a couple of lines from the .rc file that define your resource.

Comment: @MarkRansom I did that, but it didn't help unfortunately. **EDIT:** If  I do declare value as `char* value = new char[cbData+1];`, it crashes at `value[cbData+1] = 0;`

Comment: That's because `value[cbData+1]` is out of bounds. Try `value[cbData]` instead.

Comment: @MarkRansom I already mentioned, I declared it as `char* value = new char[cbData+1];`, but it also happens if I use `value[cbData]`. Simply put: Every time I access `value` after the `RegQueryValueEx` function that gives `value` its value. (That last bit sounded funny)

Comment: One more thing, try initializing `cbData`: `DWORD cbData = 0;`

Comment: @MarkRansom did that, but didn't change anything either, unfortunately.

Comment: Is this a Unicode build? You would need `wchar_t` instead of `char`, and `cbData + sizeof(wchar_t)` if so. And your code above doesn't show you nulling the last byte - you need to show your code rather than just say "I tried it", since you may have "tried it" wrong.

Comment: @JonathanPotter read the above comments. I did try nulling the last byte, still crashed. My code is there btw. Did you not read the entire post? ._. Anyway, I'll try it with wchar_t

Comment: OK, figured it out. Instead of `(LPBYTE)&value` use `(LPBYTE)value`. Otherwise you're writing to the pointer itself, not the buffer it points to, and since the string is almost certainly larger than a pointer you're getting UB. P.S. You still haven't added the .rc code to the question.

Comment: @MarkRansom oh. my. god. You are my hero! I can't believe I made such a stupid mistake <_< But thank you VERY much! I did actually add the resource file (it's the second code block) but that doesn't matter now as I can successfully read the value from the registry :) Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake was that `(LPBYTE)&value` made the function write to the pointer and not the buffer itself. It had to be changed to `(LPBYTE)value`. Thanks to Mark Ransom for this answer!